# I used to get about 380GB disk space in colab when GPU is set as the hardware accelerator. But currently it is only 68GB. Is this an update?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I am working with coco dataset which is about 22GB. I used to get enough disk space to hold large dataset like these. But these days I am only getting 68GB space. Dataset itself uses considerable disk space. I double checked weather GPU is selected or not. Is this a new limitation or changing any setting has any effect on this?

> Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
>
> overlay          69G   58G  7.4G  89% /

Comment: Try using the Flickr30 dataset, it is smaller in size but fits well in Googel Colab.

Comment: I asked the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59634631/google-colab-disk-size-with-gpu-backend.  I think they made a change without comunicating it.

Comment: Even the tensorflow example on tensorflow website for image captioning which runs on Colab , is running out of memory and is on borderline of disk space consumption,

Comment: @ArghoChatterjee maybe you should post that here:  https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/919