# Google Colab: Disk size with GPU backend

Tags: google-colaboratory

I've been using Google Colab with the GPU backend.  On December when I used it, the disk size for the GPU backend was more than 300 GB.  Now running `df -h` on the virtual machine shows this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          69G   33G   33G  50% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           6.4G     0  6.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1        75G   37G   39G  49% /opt/bin
tmpfs           6.4G   12K  6.4G   1% /var/colab
shm             5.9G  4.0K  5.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           6.4G     0  6.4G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs           6.4G     0  6.4G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs           6.4G     0  6.4G   0% /sys/firmware
```

Do you know if something has changed?  I searched the web for news about this but couldn't find any.  Before, the overlay filesystem was 359 GB.

Thanks in advance for any clues.

Bests,

B.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is a new issue.  I found this on Github:  https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/919.

What's ironic about this problem is that one proposed solution is to mount Google Drive.  Therefore I bought 200 GB of Google Drive.  However, the disk size is still an issue.  Apparently once Google Drive is mounted it starts to cache files in /root/.config/Google/DriveFS/[uniqueid]/content_cache.  The cache has no control over its size, it does not delete or replace anything, it just accumulates, and it takes all the disk making the code crash.  :(

Comment: I added an issue on GitHub about that "cache":  https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/960